# Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml. The document type declaration for root element type "hibernate-configuration" must end with '>'

Tags: xml, hibernate

I know this question has been asked many times. And I have tried all of them but all efforts were futile.

this is my hibernate.cfg.xml file

`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN" 
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>  

    <session-factory>  
       <property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property> 
<property name="connection.url">XXX</property> 
<property name="username">XXX</property> 
<property name="password">XXX</property> 
<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>  
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property> 
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<mapping resource="user.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>  

</hibernate-configuration>
```

`

Here whenever I change the **DOCTYPE** to **PUBLIC** I get following error.

`

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1491)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
    at com.javatpoint.mypackage.StoreData.main(StoreData.java:13)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: hibernate.sourceforge.net Nested exception: hibernate.sourceforge.net
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)
    ... 2 more
```

`

And when I change it to **SYSTEM** I get following error.

`

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1491)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
    at hibernate.TableView.main(TableView.java:15)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 4 of document  : The document type declaration for root element type "hibernate-configuration" must end with '>'. Nested exception: The document type declaration for root element type "hibernate-configuration" must end with '>'.
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)
    ... 2 more
```

`

user.hbm.xml file

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping SYSTEM 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" 
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">  

 <hibernate-mapping>  
  <class name="hibernate.User1" table="User1">  
    <id name="id" type="integer">  
    <column name="P_ID" precision="4" scale="0" />
     <generator class="assigned"></generator>  
    </id>  

  <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="NAME" length="30" not-null="true" />
        </property> 

       <property name="EMAIL_ID" type="string">
            <column name="EMAIL" length="40" not-null="true" />
        </property>
       <property name="COUNTRY" type="string">
            <column name="COUNTRY" length="30" not-null="true" />
        </property> 
        <property name="PASSWORD" type="string">
            <column name="PASSWORD" length="30" not-null="true" />
        </property>    
  </class>  

 </hibernate-mapping>
```

`
[image]

[image]

This is my first hibernate project. Could you please tell me where am i going wrong. And I am running this programs while connected to internet.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by downloading DTD file for both mapping and configuration and referring its path in hibernate.hbm.xml and user.hbm.xml file.

hibernate.hbm.xml

`

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
 "C:/XXX/Test/hibernate/lib/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

`

user.hbm.xml

`

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"C:/XXX/Test/hibernate/lib/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

`

Thanks